# Create Header Actions dynamically in lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-datatable, header, column

In the documentation provided by Salesforce on the '[Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)' component we find the necessary instructions (see section '**Creating Header Actions**') to create actions at header level.

It is also indicated which is the handler (**onheaderaction**) to which we must indicate the function that will be responsible for applying the logic of the selected action in the header of the table.

Let's imagine that one of the columns shows the values of a picklist (for example the `StageName` default field of the `Opportunity` object) of a record. We want the dropdown to show the valid values found in the picklist.

We can hardcode them, but if in the future these values change (either by name or by adding/removing a value from the picklist) we will have to update the lightning component. Other approach is to retrieve the values of the picklist using the wire adapter '[getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values.html)' and add these values as actions to the appropriate header.

Initially, we would have these values in the property column:

```
columns = [
  {
    label: "Offer Name",
    fieldName: "Name",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true
  },
  {
    label: "Account Name",
    fieldName: "Account.Name",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true
  },
  {
    label: "Stage",
    fieldName: "StageName",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true
  }
]
```

After retrive the picklist values and update the columns variable:

```
columns = [
  {
    label: "Offer Name",
    fieldName: "Name",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true
  },
  {
    label: "Account Name",
    fieldName: "Account.Name",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true
  },
  {
    label: "Stage",
    fieldName: "StageName",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: true,
    actions: [
      { label: "All values", checked: true, name: "all" },
      { label: "picklistValue1", checked: false, name: "picklistApiName1" },
      { label: "picklistValue1", checked: false, name: "picklistApiName1" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Let's consider another scenario. In Salesforce, the object `CampaignMember` has a `Status` default '*picklist*' field. This field behaves in a special way, because it depends on the `Campaign` object. Depending on the campaign, the values available for the Status field may vary.

**How can this happen?**

These values are stored in an object called `CampaignMemberStatus`. This object has the `CampaignId` field to relate the status with the corresponding campaign.

Referring to the example above, the actions available in the 'Status' header of a table displaying Campaign Members associated to a Campaign (`CampaignMembers` records are dynamically updated depending on a selected `Campaign`) cannot be static. At the time of selecting a campaign with different values for the `Status` field, the campaign members table would be updated to show the campaign members associated to this campaign but in addition the actions in the 'Status' header should be updated.

**With the standard Datatable component, can the two scenarios described above be addressed?**